# Seleccionar primer registro Null en consulta LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema para realizar cursos.

Tengo 2 tablas, una de nombre "Indice" y otra "Completado", en "Indice", guardo el indice del curso (es decir el curriculum, unidades, examenes, etc) y en "Completado" el `id` del usuario y el `id` de la tabla **indice** que ya completo. Luego las uno en una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select * from indice_cursos a left join completado b on a.Id=b.id_completado and b.id_usuario=$id_usuario where a.id_curso=$id_curso
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el primer registro del indice que el usuario aun no ha completado.

Adjunto imagenes de las tablas

**Tabla Indice:**
[image: Tabla indice]

**Tabla completado:**

[image: Tabla Completado]

**Consulta Left Join:**
[image: Left Joing]

¿Como debería ser la consulta?. Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema de las tablas y, si es posible, algunos datos de prueba para poder reproducir tu problema? Si no sabemos qué campos tienes y cómo los usas no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende bien. Muestra la estructura de las tablas comentando la relación que hay entre ellas. Por ejemplo, ¿qué relación hay entre el id del usuario con la tabla completado?, ¿existe también una tabla usuario?, ¿qué es un _índice_ para ti, un id de algo o una entidad de alguna tabla?, etc.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda!, ahi amplie la pregunta con imagenes, espero se entienda. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No consideres que somos exigentes, pero en las preguntas se aprecia más el código mismo que las imágenes, por dos motivos principales: 1º. En dispositivos móviles las imágenes apenas se ven, 2º. Teniendo el texto es más fácil copiarlo para reproducir la situación y ayudarte a resolver el problema. Tenlo en cuenta para futuras consultas. Por otra parte, comenta en la pregunta cómo se relacionan tus tablas y qué resultado quieres obtener exactamente, porque a simple vista parece que hay un error de diseño en ellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien, lo que te estas buscando es obtener el primer registro de la tabla `indice` que el usuario no ha completado aún.

Para esto simplemente debes:

- Indicar que quieres aquellos donde el `completado.id_usuario` es `NULL`
- Limitar la cantidad de registros a uno (`1`)
- *Opcional*: Ordenar los registros según el criterio deseado (`eg: el primero ordenados por indice.id ascendentemente`).

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM indice_cursos AS a
LEFT JOIN completado AS b
  ON a.Id = b.id_completado 
  AND b.id_usuario = $id_usuario 
WHERE a.id_curso = $id_curso 
  AND b.id_usuario IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente añade la condición para buscar los NULL.
Y si solo quieres el primer registro que encuentre pon un LIMIT.

Por tradición y legibilidad las palabras del lenguaje SQL se suelen poner en mayúsculas

```
SELECT * FROM indice_cursos a 
LEFT JOIN completado b ON a.Id=b.id_completado 
WHERE  ( b.id_usuario=$id_usuario  
    AND a.id_curso=$id_curso )
    AND b.id_completado IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Por otro lado lo normal es que en el JOIN solo haya una condición, ya que la relación entre tablas suele ser solo de un campo, la otra condición debería estar en el WHERE, y en tu pregunta no queda clara cual es la relación entre las tablas.